# creating a drop down multi level menu

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a multi level menu. I have seen yesterday the following page that I would love to do:

https://sbaueraz.github.io/

So I have been watching yesterday some tutorial and tried to create a test drop down menu with Atom (just made a search on the web and found that App, guess it's enough for what I try to do) ,
but does not seem to work properly. At least the css integration.
As I am a real beginner, I copied more or less the code from what I was watching, and tweaking a few things, trying to understand the code of course.

If someone could help me that would be great.

What I have so far (with lots of mistakes):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.multi-level,
.item ul,
.nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

#menu:checked~.multi-level,
.item:checked~ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
  <label for="menu">&#9776;</label>

  <div class="multi-level">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="A">
      <label for="A">Coupant</label>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" </a>Tête</li>
        <li><a href="#" </a>corps</li>
        <li><a href="#" </a>bras gauche</li>
        <li><a href="#" </a>bras droit </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="B">
      <label for="B">Armes à feu</label>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="B-A">
            <label for="B-A">Tête</label>

            <li>
              <div class="sub-sub-item">
                <input type="checkbox" id="B-A-A">
                <label for="B-C">1</label>

                <ul>
                  <li><a>blablablablabla
        blablablablabla</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>

      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/amandixit/rec1rfg6/1/

Comment: @arman Sharma Thanks but seems not to work well. At least the css style is now visible on the page but Drop down menus are not working still. :-)